# Align text after linebreak with CSS

Tags: css

I have a PHP output that I'm trying to align with CSS. The basic structure of the content is that I have 2 parent categories (text) and within these some sub categories (icons). I can't modify the PHP file, which is providing the output in one line. I'm trying to get the parent categories just listed underneath each other, with the sub cats next to their paren cat.

I have done quite a bit of search on this in trying to solve it but understand the main solution are the elements content \A and white-space: pre. However, this doesnt work for some reason, the text gets misaligned (see attached screenshot 1); removing the \A and white-space attribute results in the format as per attached screenshot 2.

I'm currently using the following code:

```css
.more_info {
    float: left !important;
}

[class*="parentcategory"] {
  clear: both !important;
}

.parentcategory1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.parentcategory1::before {
  content: 'Parent Cat 1:';
  visibility: visible;
}

.parentcategory2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.parentcategory2::before {
  content: 'Parent Cat 2:';
  visibility: visible;

}
.subcategory1a {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.75vh;
  color: transparent;
}

.subcategory1b {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.75vh;
  color: transparent;
}
.subcategory1c {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.75vh;
  color: transparent;
}

.subcategory2a {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  clear:none !important;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.75vh;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_info   parentcategory1" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=""></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory1a" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/openinghours.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory1b" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/kompass.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory1c" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/membership-fee.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   parentcategory2" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=""></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory2a" style="clear:both;"><span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/openinghours.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>
```

Could anyone help with this?

I would truly much appreciate it!

Many thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0fbV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxWMF.png)

**EDIT**
HTML OUTPUT CODE:

```html
<div class="more_info   parentcategory1" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=""></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory1a" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/openinghours.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory1b" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/kompass.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory1c" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/membership-fee.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   parentcategory2" style="clear:both;">
<span class="checkbox" style=""></span>Yes
</div>

<div class="more_info   subcategory2a" style="clear:both;"><span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(http://localhost/mg/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/openinghours.png) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>Yes
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEikR.png)

**EDIT 3**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToPAR.png)

Comment: Could you include the outputted HTML in your snippet? thanks

Comment: @sol : of course, see in the original post (added at the bottom). Thank you!!!

Comment: Is that HTML surrounded by a wrapper / containing element?

Comment: Yes its part of a whole page with a wrapper and many divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `float` is a good option given the markup you have.

You can apply the `float` property to every element (`.more_info`) and then apply the `clear` property to every parent category.

To target an element with a class beginning with 'parentcategory...' you can use the `*` (wildcard) selector.

Fiddle and snippet below have been simplified for demo.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/9v0b11w6/6/)

```css
.parentcategory1::before {
  content: 'Parent Cat 1:';
}

.parentcategory2::before {
  content: 'Parent Cat 2:';
}

.more_info {
  float: left;
}

[class*="parentcategory"] {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="more_info parentcategory1">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1a">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1b">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory1c">
  <span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info parentcategory2">
  <span class="checkbox" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="more_info subcategory2a"><span class="checkbox" style=" background: url(https://unsplash.it/18) no-repeat left center;background-size:18px 18px;padding-left: 21px;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @fiddle Thank you! I have included the float: left; and wildcard element as per your snippet in my code. While the 2nd parent cat is now below the 1st parent cat and well aligned left of each other, 2 new issues arised: a) the 1st parent cat has now moved up next to the previous line; and b) parent cat 2 and sub cat 2a arent vertically aligned anymore. See Screenshot in original post (EDIT 2). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @fiddle never mind issue (b) that was because I hadnt removed the white-space pre attribute from pseudo class of parent cat 2. Only issue (a) remains now - see screenshot 3 in original post.Any idea how to resolve this last piece of the puzzle? Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: Could you update the snippet to include the HTML and CSS of the preceeding elements?

Comment: of course. I have updated the code in the original post. The only changes made are in the CSS (none in the HTML): added 'float left' for '.more_info' as well as the wildcard element and removed the 'white-space: pre' and content: \A attributes for the pseudo before elements

Comment: found the problem, I still had clear:none in the parentcat classes! It works all now! THANK YOU A MILLION!!! I spent hours on this today! Thanks thanks and thanks again!